python rsa sign result in different library?
My goal is to have the signature results consistent with the server's results. I've heard that signatures may involve randomness, which leads to different results each time, but in practice, when I used the cryptography library:
signature = privateKey.sign(data, padding.PKCS1v15(), hashes.SHA256())

the results were consistent each time and matched the server's results. I want to simplify the imports and only use Crypto or cryptodome. When using cryptodome with the following code:
dataHash = SHA256.new(data)
signature = PKCS1_v1_5.new(privateKey).sign(dataHash)

the results vary each time, likely due to the salt.
I want to ask is it possible to do what cryptography does in Crypto or cryptodome that can generate the same signature every time. Thank you!

TBH, in my opinion you should only use cryptography and phase out your uses of Crypto/cryptodome...

The problem is not reproducible, PKCS1_v1_5 corresponds to RSASSA-PKCS-v1_5 and is deterministic as the following example shows: https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/1m0C

Incidentally, Crypto is legacy, is no longer maintained and should not be used at all, as AKX has already pointed out. However, as far as I know, there is no reason not to use its successor, PyCryptodome (apart from personal preference perhaps).

...likely due to the salt... there is no salt.
